# blank lines when deleting nodes using JOOX and XPATH in Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm using JOOX to process a xml file which I want to delete some nodes by a pattern.

This is a file example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<results>
   <result>
      <location>5</location>
   </result>
   <result>
      <location>19</location>
   </result>
   <result>
      <location>23</location>
   </result>
</results>
```

This is the Java code:

```
File file = new File("myfile.xml")
Document document = $(file).document();
$(document).xpath("//result[@location = id]").remove();
```

The deletion works ok but when I try to write the document to the file:

```
$(document).write(file);
```

All the deleted nodes produce blank lines in my xml file. I also realised that there is no xml header.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

This is the produced file if I try to delete the location 5:

```
<results>



   <result>
      <location>19</location>
   </result>
   <result>
      <location>23</location>
   </result>
</results>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is this tagged as XSLT? Can you use XSLT?

Comment: you need a transformer usually to transform xml after you modify document

Comment: @svasa how can I do that?